# SP2010 - Calendar - Display Form with Edit Series

Tags: 2010

SharePoint 2010 - Calendar

REQUIREMENT:  I have a requirement to have a list view of events filtered by the user that will be displayed on a blank aspx page.  The user needs the ability to edit/delete an event for that day or by series.

ISSUE:  When clicking on an event, the display form will open but the ribbon will not have the option to 'Edit Series'.  If an event that is recurring is clicked on from the calendar view, both 'Edit Item' and 'Edit Series' options are available.

How do I make it so that for recurring events, the display form has both the 'Edit Item' and 'Edit Series' appear on the ribbon?

Thanks